# Error of "raster", "terra" when publishing to Shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

When trying to publish my shinyweb to shinyapps.io, I encounter an error says

```
Error: 
* Application depends on package "raster" but it is not installed.
   Please resolve before continuing.

* Application depends on package "terra" but it is not installed.
   Please resolve before continuing.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Failed to infer source for package 'raster'; using latest available version on CRAN instead
2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Failed to infer source for package 'terra'; using latest available version on CRAN instead
3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Failed to infer source for package 'raster'; using latest available version on CRAN instead
4: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  Failed to infer source for package 'terra'; using latest available version on CRAN instead
5: Unable to package DESCRIPTION files: Couldn't find DESCRIPTION file for raster 
Execution halted
```

As it said, I install the package of terra and raster it still not working. I wonder how can I fix this? Thank you in advance!!

[Here is what the error look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksFL5.png)